# JSON parse error on ajax call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

I have this javascript function that I use in an MVC project. It's been working fine, no code has changed, other than some nuget packages have been updated since the last time I tested it (not sure which ones). Now suddenly I'm getting a **parse error**.  The parameter being passed is simply 'indoor' or 'outdoor', and just to make sure that had nothing to do with the issue, I hard-coded it instead of passing it, both with and without the `JSON.stringify` to see if that mattered, which it didn't.  Any ideas why this is suddenly breaking?

```
    function LoadHobbies(category) {
        var data = {
            type: category
        };
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: '/Hobby/LoadHobbies',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    }
```

`Remote Address:[::1]:9925
Request URL:http://localhost:9925/Hobby/LoadHobbies
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:17
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:9925
Origin:http://localhost:9925
Referer:http://localhost:9925/Account/Index
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payloadview source
{type: "indoor"}
type: "indoor"
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:162
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 10 Jan 2015 01:28:13 GMT
Location:/Login/Index?ReturnUrl=%2fHobby%2fLoadHobbies
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:5.2
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RDpcVXNlcnNcQW5kcmV3XERvY3VtZW50c1xjb2RlXEhvYmJ5TWF0cml4U29sdXRpb25NVkNcSG9iYnlNYXRyaXhXZWJcSG9iYnlcTG9hZEhvYmJpZXM=?=`

Comment: What error is it? Client side or server side. Please post the erro.

Comment: It's a javascript error that only shows if I use a .fail() from where I call this. It never calls the controller on the server.

Comment: Can you check the network tab on the browser to verify it's not doing a call to the server?

Comment: Try this instead of `data`: `'{ "type" : ' + category + ' }';`. This is an obscure case, make sure `data` variable is not duplicated or at least change its name to `_data`

Comment: whatever the server is returning isnt valid json

Comment: I tried those things, the call isn't making it to the server.

Comment: whenit says parser erro can you click on it to go to the error?

Comment: use Google Chrome debug tool and check `data` contents handy.

Comment: Paste the raw response. The format of JSON would be wrong.

Comment: Added network traffic for this call.  Seems like I'm getting a status 302 (haven't seen this before), but the JSON looks okay I think.

Comment: I thought you said that the call wasn't making it to the server. The above screen shot you provided shows that is not the case

Comment: Since it's hitting the server It's most likely something has changed. 302 is a redirect, so that's why it's not hitting your controller.

Comment: I've got a breakpoint on the controller and it's not getting there.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm a moron. I had added a global authentication check a while back, and forgot to put an [AllowAnonymous] attribute on this controller. So I was right about it not reaching the breakpoint, and you were right about the redirect. Sorry I wasted everyone's time.

Thanks,

Andrew